# Python scripts that depend on binaries... how to distribute?

Tags: python, software-distribution

I have a codebase that includes some C++ code and Python scripts that make use of the resulting binaries (via the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module).

```
root/
    experiments/
        script_1.py (needs to call binary_1)
    clis/
        binary_1.cc
        binary_1
```

What's the best way to refer to the binary from the Python scripts?

- A relative path from the Python script's directory to the binary, which assumes the user will be running the Python script from a particular directory
- Just the binary name, which assumes the user will have added the binary's directory to the `$PATH` variable, or copied the binary to `/usr/local/bin`, or something
- Something else?

Comment: Is it a tool that will only be called from the python module, and never used alone?

Comment: @Keith It's also used on its own, aside from being called from Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your binaries are pre-compiled you can use the [data_files](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) parameter to setuptools. Have it installed in /usr/local/bin.

```
data_files=[("/usr/local/bin", glob("bin/*"))], ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `__file__` to find out the location of the Python script, so it wouldn't matter where the user ran the script from.

```
path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(
         os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'clis', 'binary_1'
       ))
```

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, the best way to integrate your C(pp) code in your Python program is to [make a compiled Python module out of the C(pp) code](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html) instead of using the subprocess module as you are now doing.

In addition to a more consistent and readable Python codebase, you get the added benefit of modularity (solving among others the $PATH issues) and can [use distutils as build tool](http://docs.python.org/extending/building.html#building). Distribution is also easier, then, as setup.py automates it.

Comment: One other thing... my cpp binaries are stand-alone command line tools, useful on their own, apart from being called by the Python scripts, so converting them to compiled python modules isn't really the way to go, I think.

Comment: It is still the way to go. You need to review your design: make a library out of the Cpp tools, and make natural use of it both in the Cpp front-end of the Python module and in a command-line front-end. You split your code in 3 sub-projects; this kind of modularity is good: these design principles actually exist exactly to address the kind of problem you are facing now.